# How to fix a broken SQL view

Tags: mysql, view

I am using the open source CMS pimcore (http://www.pimcore.org), which runs on a MySQL backend.

It uses fairly complicated views to represent objects and one of them has become broken at some stage when a column in another table being referenced by the view was renamed. Whenever I try to interact with the table via SQL commands I receive the error:

> View 'barriste_website.object_6' references invalid table(s) or
> column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use
> them

I would like to simply update the view to reference the renamed columns, but I need to know the current structure of the view before I start poking around - how exactly do I retrieve the structure of the view once it is broken? I've tried

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW object_6
```

but I receive the same error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'v';
```

reference: [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA VIEWS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views-table.html)

**SQL Server:**

```
USE databasename
GO

EXEC sp_helptext viewName
```

or also a query like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as ViewName,
VIEW_DEFINITION as ViewDefinition
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views
```

where you could add a `WHERE` to only retrieve one view

Comment: Thanks Davide - I think sp_helptext is MSSQL only, I need MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

Simply delete the view with "drop view object_6", then go into the pimcore backend and save the class again. The view is then regenerated automatically.

Comment: doesnt sound like a good idea, deleting will delete all reference to the SQL statement, which one needs in order to recompose the view after changing column names in referenced table(s).

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work with pimcore, however I had this issue with a standard AWS MySQL DB and deleting the view does NOT automatically regenerate it. Luckily I had a copy of the view, found that there were columns that were renamed, updated the names in the code and just executed the view code. It naturally created the correct view and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was to use `ORDER BY` with an *alias* causing the issue. I changed my view from:

```
CREATE VIEW v_storename_totalnamelength AS
SELECT
  (char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`) + char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`)) AS `TotalNameLength`
FROM
  `promoter`.`v_storename_extracted` `a`
ORDER BY
  `TotalNameLength` DESC
;
```

to:

```
CREATE VIEW v_storename_totalnamelength AS
SELECT
  (char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`) + char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`)) AS `TotalNameLength`
FROM
  `promoter`.`v_storename_extracted` `a`
ORDER BY
  (char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`) + char_length(`a`.`ExtractedLongName`)) DESC
;
```