# MySQL can run select * query but not select column on view

Tags: mysql, sql, database

(This has been resolved. See answer below)

I've created a view with the following query:

```
SELECT TableA.ColA as ColA, User.ID as UserID, User.FirstName, User.LastName, User.Email, TableC.ID as RoleID, TableC.Name as Role FROM Permission
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ColA = TableB.ID
LEFT JOIN TableD ON TableD.ID = TableB.OrganizationID
LEFT JOIN User ON User.ID = TableA.UserID
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableC.ID = TableA.RoleID
WHERE User.Active = 1 AND (TableA.ResourceType = 1
OR (TableA.ResourceType = 5 AND TableD.ID = TableB.OrganizationID))
OR User.Active = 1 AND TableC.ID = 1
ORDER BY ColA, UserID ASC
```

The view was created successfully and works as intended. I can do a `SELECT * ON view_test` on the view without issue. However, if I attempt to select a specific column from the view, such as `SELECT ColA FROM view_test`, it returns with the following error message:

```
#1356 - View 'database.view_test' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

The account I'm running this on is root and I've re-granted access to everything in this database, should something have messed up for some reason. I've looked at the view in the `mysql` portion of the database and it seems fine. I can run it without issue. I can do a `SELECT ColA FROM ([view_sql_block_from_above]) as a` and it works fine as well. It's only after having been created as a view that it has these issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=== Edit ===

Below is the output from `SELECT COLUMNS FROM view_test`

```
show columns from view_test;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ColA      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ColB      | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| ColC      | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ColD      | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ColE      | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ColF      | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| ColG      | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: try SHOW COLUMNS FROM view_test and share the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix a broken SQL view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150804/how-to-fix-a-broken-sql-view)

Comment: Added output from show columns to question above.

Comment: I do not see where you join TableA table. Check the SELECT query firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this. It ended up being that the view has a built in ORDER BY ColA command in it, however if ColA was not part of the query against the view itself, it would provide that error message.

So, to resolve this, I would just remove the `ORDER BY` from the view or include the ColA column in the query. Alternatively, I changed the `ORDER BY` from ColA to TableA.ColA, so the ordering happens in the source table rather than the derived view.

Thanks for all who helped in this resolution.